# Magento2: is Product configurable?

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product

How can I know if a product is configurable (color, size, shape) or can be added directly to the cart (it is unique without configuration possible) **programmatically**?

For example: I have a shirt without attributes, then my method `canBeAddedDirectly($product)` should return true.

However, another shirt has 3 colors then, my method `canBeAddedDirectly($product)` should return false, because I need to choose a color (or other attributes) before.

Comment: can you brief given your questions? what your expecting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check if it's configurable and if it doesn't have any custom options (since simple products can have custom options those can require modification as well). Something like this might get you started:

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product
 * @return bool
 */
public function canBeAddedDirectly(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product) {
    return $product->getTypeId() === 'configurable' && !empty($product->getOptions());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

see what `$product->getTypeId()` returns.
if it returns `configurable` it is configurable.

Answer (score 2):

`Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface` inject in your file and check

> check condition  $product->getTypeId() == 'configurable'

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2 any simple product can become a configurable product.
It is considered a configurable product if it has been configured with a set of child products. It will then show as 'Configurable' in your admin products list.